# How to get ARM NEON dot production ("UDOT") instruction support in Android NDK project?

Tags: arm, neon

I am building an android NDK project using ARM NEON on one Snapdragon 845 phone.

After reading the post https://community.arm.com/developer/tools-software/tools/b/tools-software-ides-blog/posts/exploring-the-arm-dot-product-instructions, I would like to use `UDOT` to do the convolution. However, the `UDOT` instruction is not recognized. I tried the code

```
static unsigned long long read_id_aa64isar0()
{
 unsigned long long id_aa64isar0;

 __asm ("MRS %x0, ID_AA64ISAR0_EL1 \n" : "=r" (id_aa64isar0) );

return (id_aa64isar0);
}

static bool dot_product_supported()
{
 if (read_id_aa64isar0() & 0x0000100000000000ULL)
     return true;
 else
     return false;
}
```

to try to confirm dot product support, it reports ERROR `Illegal instruction` .

My Application.mk file is like

```
APP_STL := c++_static
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := clang
APP_PLATFORM := android-21
APP_ABI := arm64-v8a
```

And the flags of my Android.mk is like

```
LOCAL_ARM_NEON  := true
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -march=armv8.2-a -Werror -O3
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -fopenmp
LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -fopenmp
```

I tried to change `-march=armv8-a` to `-march=armv8.2-a` but it reports error `error: unknown value 'armv8.2-a' for -march`.

The NDK version I used is `r14b`. Can I know how I can have the support for `UDOT`? Thank you！

Comment: Is that an error at compile time or run time?  I wonder if your assembler knows about `ID_AA64ISAR0_EL1`.

Comment: @NateEldredge Hi Nate, the `Illegal instruction` error is in run time. And if I change `-march=armv8-a` to `-march=armv8.2-a`, the `error: unknown value 'armv8.2-a' for -march` error is in compile time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. As far as I know, `MRS` is a non-user mode only instruction.
2. NDK `r14b` is from March 2017, the same year the first bunch of `armv8.2-a` was launched.
   And thus, I doubt that the compiler supports `armv8.2-a`.
   You should try `r17c` or later.

Comment: Hi Jake, thank you very much. As you suggested, I switched r14b to r18b and then updated Application.mk and Android.mk as above. (The change is updated in the original post. ) Then the build is successful. No more `error: unknown value 'armv8.2-a' for -march.` is shown. But I still got `Illegal instruction` when run the code. Do you know why? Thank you!

Comment: @KathyLee As I said above `mrs` is most probably a non-user mode only instruction which means it's only valid in superuser, exception/interrupt mode. All Android apps run in user mode unless you modded the device which is virtually impossible/infeasible these days.

Comment: Thank you! Actually I am using the devboard so I guess I am the superuser?  I finally have it run because I change to Snapdragon 855. 845 is too old to make it run...Thank you!